# How to add cumulative distribution function in canvasjs?

Tags: geolocation, canvasjs

I am working in an company as a trainee front end developer. I have been asked to research on how to gather or collect some datapoints on a particular spot in Google Maps and visualize them nicely on a graph.

Actually he liked one of my ideas. But he wants me to do this graph by cumulative distribution function.

Please see the codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>  

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

    animationEnabled: true,

    theme: "dark1",

    title:{

        text: "Network Technology on a Particular Spot"
    },

    axisY: {

        title: "Movement Category(Avg.)",

        suffix: "%"

    },

    legend: {
        cursor:"pointer",
        itemclick : toggleDataSeries
    },

    toolTip: {
        shared: true,
        content: toolTipFormatter,
        suffix: "%"
    },

    data: [{
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "2G",
        color: "blue",
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 23, label: "STANDSTILL" },
            { y: 36, label: "ON FOOT" },
            { y: 43, label: "ON VEHICLE" },
            {isCumulativeSum : true}
            ]
    },

    {
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "3G",
        color: "yellow",
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 12, label: "STANDSTILL" },
            { y: 86, label: "ON FOOT" },
            { y: 72, label: "ON VEHICLE" },
            {isCumulativeSum : true}
        ]
    },

    {
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "4G",
        color: "red",
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 22, label: "STANDSTILL" },
            { y: 16, label: "ON FOOT" },
            { y: 22, label: "ON VEHICLE" },
            {isCumulativeSum : true}
        ]
    },

    {
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "LTE",
        color: "green",
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 36, label: "STANDSTILL" },
            { y: 12, label: "ON FOOT" },
            { y: 39, label: "ON VEHICLE" },
            {isCumulativeSum : true}
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

function toolTipFormatter(e) {
    var str = "";
    var total = 0 ;
    var str3;
    var str2 ;
    for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
        var str1 = "<span style= \"color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "\">" + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: <strong>"+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong> <br/>" ;
        total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
        str = str.concat(str1);
    }
    str2 = "<strong>" + e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong> <br/>";
    str3 = "<span style = \"color:Tomato\">Total: </span><strong>" + total + "</strong><br/>";
    return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
}

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
    if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    }
    else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
    chart.render();
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regarding your questions, it looks like you have used words that brought several of them to the attention of my begging filter, and I have edited a good deal of pleading out of a number of them. Having taken a look at a couple of them just now, I notice from you comments asking people to do your work for you. **This is not what Stack Overflow is for**. Stack Overflow is comprised mostly of volunteers who will help you on things where you have made a solid and genuine effort yourself. Do not try to pressure, beg or cajole people into assisting you, as people are here in their free time.

Comment: Given your -9 question, I would guess you are teetering on the edge of a question ban, so I would advise you to rethink your approach to this site if you can. Readers do want to help you, but they want to see an effort from you, and they do not want to see comments asking people to finish a piece of work off. Even if you are in a rush or your work is urgent, it is also best not to mention this, since volunteers are under no obligations here whatsoever. If you can follow this approach, you may also find that you receive less downvotes, which is very helpful for you.